# A circle and its tangents. General proof with them

Tags: geometry

[image]

Based off of the construction I do know that $XZ = SZ$. As far as using this information to prove it I have no idea. It appears that $Y$ is completely dependent on where point $X$ is. If $X$ was farther down on the circle then it would make $Y$ be more closer to the circle and thus keep the distance equal with $SZ$ and $ZY$. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just join OZ. Then prove the two triangles just formed are congruent.

Comment: That doesnt tell me why $ZY = SZ$ as far as I can tell

Comment: The previous comment is just a hint working as a starter. Some follow-up actions need to be taken. Answer is posted.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

After joining OZ, triangles SOZ and XOZ are congruent. That makes $\angle 11 = \angle 12$.

Note also that OSZX is a cyclic quadrilateral. That makes $\angle 12 = \angle 13$.

In the semi-circle, $\angle 13 + \angle 21 = 90^0$.

But $\angle 21 = \angle 22$ (angles in alternate segment)

Therefore, $\angle 22 + \angle 11 = ... = 90^0$. This means $\angle 30 = 90^0$

Thus, OZ // NY.

The last result, together with SO = ON, implies SZ = ZY (intercept theorem)

Answer (score 0):

$\triangle NSY$ is a right triangle, so $\angle ZYX + \angle ONX = 90^\circ$.

$\triangle ONX$ is isosceles, so $\angle ONX = \angle OXN$.

$NXY$ is a straight line, so $\angle OXN + \angle ZXY = 90^\circ$.

Putting that all together yields $\angle ZYX = \angle ZXY$.